# subprocess.Popen() wont pick up scp's output to stdout

Tags: subprocess, stdout, scp

I have a folder on my local computer named `move` and inside move, there are three files names `movefile1.txt`, `movefile2.txt` and `movefile3.txt`. I also have the following bash script named `minscp.sh` on my computer:

```
#! /bin/bash

PORT="22"
SOURCE_PATH="/path/to/folder/move"
SAVE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/"
USER="ubuntu@"
IP="<aws public ip>"

scp -r -P $PORT $SOURCE_PATH $USER@$IP:$SAVE_PATH
```

If I `cd` into the folder that contains this scrip and I run `./minscp.sh` then the following is returned:

```
movefile1.txt                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
movefile2.txt                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
movefile3.txt                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

I want to call this script with `subprocess.Popen()` and I want to capture each line that is printed out. Usually the following woks for me, but in this case using `scp`, I am not getting the result that I expected to:

```
>>> with subprocess.Popen(
...     [
...         path_to_bash,
...     ],
...     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
...     universal_newlines=True
...     ) as p:
...     for i, line in enumerate(p.stdout):
...         print(f"{i} : {line}")
...
>>>
```

This function runs and will successfully move the files, however nothing is printed to the console. I tried using `stderr` instead and I got the following:

```
>>> with subprocess.Popen(
...     [
...         path_to_bash,
...     ],
...     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
...     universal_newlines=True
...     ) as p:
...     for i, line in enumerate(p.stderr):
...         print(f"{i} : {line}")
...
movefile1.txt                                                  100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
movefile2.txt                                                  100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
movefile3.txt                                                  100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
>>>
```

Notice that nothing was actually printed in the `for` loop and that the response I know got but did not get above when trying to call the response from `stdout` happens sometime before the loop.

How can I capture the response line by line as the processes is running?

#### EDIT

I found out if I add the verbose tag to the script, then I almost get what I want. In other words, if I change the `scp` call in `minscp.sh` to the following:

```
scp -v -r -P $PORT $SOURCE_PATH $USER@$IP:$SAVE_PATH
```

then `subprocesses.Popen()` gives me the following

```
>>> with subprocess.Popen(
...     [
...         path_to_bash,
...     ],
...     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
...     universal_newlines=True
...     ) as p:
...     for i, line in enumerate(p.stderr):
...         if line.startswith("Sending"):
...             f =line.split(" ")[-1]
...             print(f"{i} : {f}", end="")
...
90 : movefile1.txt
movefile1.txt                                                  100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
95 : movefile2.txt
movefile2.txt                                                  100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
100 : movefile3.txt
movefile3.txt                                                  100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
>>>
```

and then if I add in `stdout` this will become

```
>>> with subprocess.Popen(
...     [
...         path_to_bash,
...     ],
...     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
...     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
...     universal_newlines=True
...     ) as p:
...     for i, line in enumerate(p.stderr):
...         if line.startswith("Sending"):
...             f =line.split(" ")[-1]
...             print(f"{i} : {f}", end="")
...
90 : movefile1.txt
95 : movefile2.txt
100 : movefile3.txt
>>>
```

This technically accomplishes what I want but does not really answer my question as to how can I capture the following, which I am suppressing with stdout and replacing with the line from the `scp` call with the `-v` tag in place:

```
movefile1.txt                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
movefile2.txt                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
movefile3.txt                                                   100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Comment: Try printing it out as `print(f"{i} : {line!r}")`

Comment: @user3840170 that didn't help unfortunately